# Sync Choregraphe and Matlab

Tags: python, c++, matlab, nao-robot

I have a Wizard of Oz experiment using Choregraphe to make a NAO perform certain tasks running on machine A. The participant interacting with the NAO also interacts with a machine B. When I start the experiment (in Choregraphe on machine A) I want a certain MATLAB script to start on machine B. I.e. Choregraphe will initiate the MATLAB script.

Do you have any suggestions of how to do this? My programming are limited to that of MATLAB and R, while Choregraphe is well integrated with Python and C++ hence my question here on Stack.

Kind Regards,
KD

Comment: Can you make your question a bit clearer? It looks like you just want a MATLAB code running on computer B after computer A script finished, however, there are about 10 quite specific concepts in the first paragraph that seem unnecessary. Is it  *likert-scale in set time intervals* important to what you are trying to do?

Comment: I edited the question and I hope that it is more clear now. Feel free to ask if there is any ambiguity.

Comment: Does the NAO have access to Machine B? How does NAO has access to it? via what protocols? Can you make the NAO execute a command in Machine B? Could you make it execute `matlab scriptname.m` in commands?

Comment: No, the NAO only got access to Machine A via ethernet. Machine A and B are connected to the same network. Essentially, what I want to know is if  Choregraphe can execute `matlab scriptname.m` on Machine B from Machine A?

Comment: My best guess: Make NAO execute script 1 in Machine A, make script 1 execute script 2 in Machine B.

Answer (score 0):

Using NAO C++ SDK, it may be possible to make a MEX-FILE in Matlab that "listens" to NAO. Then NAO just has to raise an event in its memory (ALMemory) that Matlab would catch to start running the script.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that solution and get back to you.